# Get maximum value by arranging numbers of various digits

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I was trying to write a function largest_number() that can output the maximum value by arranging the orders of a list of given numbers (eg. 21,2 should give 221. 543,5432,1 should give 54354321). This is a homework problem that I have tested using many many cases but didn't get any wrong answer. However the grading system kept telling me that I have the wrong output (without showing the output on their end). I suspect there 's a tiny bit of the code that resulted in wrong output in some special cases, but I coudn't find it.

```
    #Uses python3
    #%%

    import functools


    def greater(str1, str2):

        if str1==str2:
            return 1 


        for i in range(min(len(str1),len(str2))):

            if str1[i]>str2[i]:
                return 1

            if str1[i]<str2[i]:
                return -1


        if len(str1)>len(str2):
            if str1[len(str1)-len(str2)-1]>str1[0]:
                return 1
            else:
                return -1

        if len(str1)<len(str2):
            if str2[len(str2)-len(str1)-1]>str2[0]:
                return -1
            else:
                return 1

    def largest_number(a):

        a=list(map(str,a))
        a_sorted=sorted(a,key=functools.cmp_to_key(greater),reverse=True)
        largest=int(''.join(a_sorted))
        return(largest)


    #test cases:
    largest_number([21,2])
    largest_number([543,5432,1])
```

Comment: Hint: here's a test case that fails: [456, 45641]

Comment: This problem can be practiced for free at https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-number/

They'll have plenty of test cases for you.  I think you're trying to do a lexicographical sort by itself and then reversing it.  

A lex sort is definitely needed, afaik, but maybe you're not applying it on what you need to apply it on.  And also, while I applaud showing your work, strings will automatically do a lex comparison in python so you can replace your greater function with just return str1 > str2 ? 1 : -1  (unless your teacher is a stickler)

Comment: @FredMan, `str1 > str2 ? 1 : -1` is not valid syntax. I suppose you mean `return 1 if str1 > str2 else -1`, but it would not give the intended result. "greater" has a slightly different meaning here. For instance, the test case in the first comment above would also fail with such an implementation.

Comment: @trincot, oh, yes, I'm sorry, I spend most of my time in java and forgot python doesn't have the ternary operator, but I think you'll find I did not say that that one change would resolve his problem.  "A lex sort is definitely needed, afaik, but maybe you're not applying it on what you need to apply it on" was meant as a hint without giving away the answer.  As far as i can tell his greater function works fine as a lex sort, but he's not applying it to the appropriate content.  It's just that python already does a lex comparison for strings so it'd be safer not to bother reinventing the wheel

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone:
    1. Thanks for providing the test case [456, 45641]
    2. Python’s internal lexical sort doesn’t always give the write result: eg. ’21’>’2’ gives True, but I want 221, not 212
    3. I have checked Leet code but it has a class solution that I have tried to turn into functions but failed.

I just think there must be simpler way to solve this. I had a solution that print out all possible combination of strings and pick the largest, but after submitted, the automatic grading system told me it’s too memory efficient and I have to optimize my code…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in `greater` is not entirely correct where it deals with the case that one string is a left-substring of the other:

```
    if len(str1)>len(str2):
        if str1[len(str1)-len(str2)-1]>str1[0]:
            return 1
        else:
            return -1
```

Here you don't deal correctly with the case where `str1[len(str1)-len(str2)-1]` is equal to `str1[0]`. In that case you should iterate further, increasing the index in both strings (much like you did in the first part of the algorithm). So change the above code to:

```
    if len(str1)>len(str2):
        for i in range(len(str2),len(str1)):
            if str1[i]>str1[i-len(str2)]:
                return 1
            if str1[i]<str1[i-len(str2)]:
                return -1
```

... and do a similar change for the mirrored case.

However, there is a much easier way to approach this. In the `greater` function you could just concatenate the two strings in the two possible ways, and compare to see which of these two is the greater one:

```
def cmp(a, b): # This function was included in Python 2.x, but no longer in 3.x
    return (a > b) - (a < b)

def greater(str1, str2):
    return cmp(str1 + str2, str2 + str1)
```

Comment: Thanks trincot! Your second apporach is so neat and I like it very much. My final answer was using your second approach with my own largest_number() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that problem with Itertools Module:

```
import itertools
import functools

#"my_list" object is a list of string objects.
def largest_number(my_list):
    answer = 0
    for i in itertools.permutations(my_list):
        x = int(functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,i))
        if x > answer: 
            answer = x
    return answer
```

This code works because the "permutations" method of itertools module return all possible cases of combinations of a list.

Comment: That's going to be quite inefficient on larger inputs.

Comment: While this works, an interviewer wouldn't like this solution.  While the space is fine because python uses a generator for the permutation object (I believe?) but the time complexity is O(N!)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this and reply as a comment above. It's memory inefficient since it tries to render all possible combinatinos